# MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed? How does this work?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

Straight to the point:

Where can I place the algoritm for password hash encryption in Membership Provider?
or: Where did Microsoft team place the encryption method?

Because: I chose to have it Hash but password ended up in my database are plain.

Thank you very much :)

----- Update

Sorry for not mention, im using my own custom provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specified in the [Membership Provider configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b9hw62f.aspx) of your webconfig, using the [add element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whae3t94.aspx):

```
<!-- SqlMembershipProvider syntax -->
<add name="string" 
  type="string" 
  connectionStringName="string"
  applicationName="MyApplication"
  commandTimeout
  description
  enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
  enablePasswordReset="true"
  passwordFormat="Hashed"
  minRequiredPasswordLength
  minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters
  passwordStrengthRegularExpression
/>
```

The default algorithm is SHA1, as defined in the membership provider, but you can override this if you want to using the `hashAlgorithmType` attribute:

```
<membership
  defaultProvider="provider name"
  userIsOnlineTimeWindow="number of minutes"
  hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
  <providers>...</providers>
</membership>
```

For more details on providing your own algorithm, see ["Mapping Algorithm Names to Cryptography Classes"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/693aff9y.aspx).

Note that the format overrides things like password retrieval - hashed passwords can't be retrieved, and a provider should return an exception if GetPassword is called on them when the password is hashed (see [EnablePasswordRetrieval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.enablepasswordretrieval.aspx) property).

If you have written your own MembershipProvider, I suggest you take a look at the ["How to: Sample Membership Provider Implementation"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75.aspx), especially the methods `EncodePassword` and `UnencodePassword`.

Comment: Yes, i've worked out to include generation of hashcode at CreateUser and ValidateUser, ChangePassword. these 3 method used password so it's nessesary to hash all of them.

Comment: Yes - each of those will need to call into the EncodePassword method.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I think passwords are saved in plain text because 'password retrieval' is enabled.
You can disable this by setting <membership ... enablePasswordRetrieval="False"/> in Web.config.

Comment: Even though i tried to turn this option to false, the hash couldn't make it to the database... I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It's an option on the provider in the XML config. The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998347.aspx) show that you just set "passwordFormat='hashed'".

Comment: MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed ->  i go straight for this in my config

Comment: And it's not working? What provider are you actually using? The SqlMembershipProvider? Check the source code for it, and see how it makes use of that field.

Comment: Actually, im using my own Provider, i forgot to mention abouve, can you send me a source for the CreateUser method?

Comment: I think there could be the problem from my code that might submit the password directly to database, but where can i find the method to hash the password before i can submit it to my database? That's might be the problem for this case.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely the problem. In that case you just want to learn how to hash the password before setting it. Hash it with SHA-256 or above: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256(VS.71).aspx, there are plenty of examples how to do it (take the bytes that you get, and convert into Hex (base16) and store.